# Laravel Notification Redirect to Newly Created Item

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to have it so that anytime a new Doctor is registered, it triggers a Laravel notification to send me an email. Here is my current code:

**Controller**

```
$doctor = new Doctor();
$doctor->practice_id = $request->practice;
$doctor->first_name = $request->first_name;
$doctor->last_name = $request->last_name;
$doctor->type = $request->type;
$doctor->npi = $request->npi;
$doctor->license = $request->license;
$doctor->dea = $request->dea;
$doctor->is_approved = 0;
$doctor->is_ffs = 0;
$doctor->ffs_id = null;
$doctor->save();

Notification::route('mail', 'admin@test.com')->notify(new NewDoctor($doctor));
```

**NewDoctor Notification**

```
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail'];
}

public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->greeting('Doctor Registered!')
        ->line('A new doctor has been submitted for approval.')
        ->action('View Doctor', route('doctors.show', [$this->doctor]));
}
```

This is returning the following error: `Undefined property: App\Notifications\NewDoctor::$doctor`

I'm assuming that for some reason the `doctor` `id` just is not passing through, but I have no idea how to make that pass in.

Comment: You are passing `$doctor` in constructor of `NewDoctor`. You need to have a `__construct($someVariable)` constructor to initialize that value in your notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private $doctor;

public function __construct($doctor)
{
    $this->doctor = $doctor;

}
```

Declare a constructor in your `New Doctor` notification class and then only you would be able to use the `$doctor` variable.